# Django - Access django context array with variable from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django

Let's say I have a dynamic JavaScript variable

`var i = 1;`

Also I have a context `users` which is an array. The problem is, How to access `users[i]` in JavaScript?

I've tried like this

```
alert("{{ users." + i + ".name }}");
```

But it didn't works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have user key available then you can get user detail as below.
var i = 1;

var user = user[i];

alert(user.name);